How do I make a whole Unity tilemap invisible programmatically while still being enabled?
I want to be able to change the visibility of a Unity tilemap programmatically in C#, while keeping the tilemap enabled.
Looking at the documentation of TilemapRenderer, there is a property isVisible, but it is read-only, so I cannot do something like the following:
Transform myTilemap = GameObject.Find("My Tilemap").transform;
myTilemap.GetComponent<TilemapRenderer>().isVisible = false;

It also does not have a Color property, unlike for example a SpriteRenderer, so I cannot set its alpha value to zero like one could do with a sprite.
I do not want to make the tilemap no longer enabled.
How may I do this?

enabled on the TilemapRenderer is the property you're looking for, the main Tilemap object will still be enabled:
Transform myTilemap = GameObject.Find("My Tilemap").transform;
myTilemap.GetComponent<TilemapRenderer>().enabled = false;

This works for any other Renderer, or even any other component.


I do not want to make the tilemap [or tilemap renderer] no longer enabled.

Alternatives:

Tilemap has a color property, not TilemapRenderer. You could also set that to new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
Change the tilemap's GameObject's layer to one that is excluded by the camera's culling mask
Set the parent Grid's enabled property to false: tilemap.GetComponentInParent<Grid>().enabled = false
Set TilemapRenderer.maskInteraction to SpriteMaskInteraction.VisibleInsideMask (assuming you don't use sprite masks)


Unfortunately, I don't want to change enabled. I need the tilemap to be enabled for other reasons, just for it to be invisible.

Try setting enabled to false for the parent Grid, then? Or add it to a layer that's excluded from the main camera? Or changing Tilemap.color?

What you have written does work actually - the Tilemap is enabled, but not the TilemapRenderer. Thank you.
